# 16.04 LTS No Files Found In ZPOOL HDDs

Tags: 16.04, mount, zfs

After upgrading to 16.04.1 from 14.01, my zpool 2 HDDs mount, `/mnt/data1` shows 0 files when using `ls -l`. It had 4GBs of media files on it before the upgrade.

Running `sudo blkid` shows this for the dual drives:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="data1" UUID="10966378473217785525" UUID_SUB="14817207932203736137" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs" PARTUUID="e81a7839-39f5-0045-9e6e-0a27918384c6"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="data1" UUID="10966378473217785525" UUID_SUB="16920690055977428929" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-8d703f74175288c8" PARTUUID="8329dfc3-4bb4-d642-ae0e-595b98e4d7f9"
```

Is `zfs` supported on 16.04 LTS? Did the upgrade format the disk?

Answer (score 1):

The zpool was waiting to be imported. Running this command did it.

`$ zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id poolname`